# Gap above div from css in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html

We've got a problem in chrome where the div won't sit against the top of the page.

Here is the page http://beektest.co/s27

The problem is coming from http://gms.beektest.co/resources/css/leanorama.css (at least if I remove this css file the Flash div sits at the top of the page.

Can anyone see anything obvious of why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding your own custom css to the selector like this:

```
::before,
::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

Basically, we're giving the css generated content a zero height.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble `line-height` here doesn't apply to all elements, but it applies to `:before` and `:after` pseudo :)

Answer (score 2):

Removing the following from leanorama.css (line 21) seemed to fix the gap:

```
::before,
::after {
  content: "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seemed to work - but it broke the HTML5 pano player which uses it.. I'll speak to those guys and see what they think.

Answer (score -1):

In your CSS put `line-height: 0;`

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: You will end up writing `line-height` for each element, I've not tested, infact I haven't read the question but applying `line-height` in general is wrong, target the element specifically and do it.

Comment: He is already applying * to margin and padding that is wrong as well correct?

Comment: Margins and paddings are fine, as that's a standard, every designer resets them and applies custom to keep consistent positioning across the browsers, setting `line-height: 0;` means you will have to assign `line-height` to each and every element which is not good